# Variables in object names

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, for-loop

Is it possible to get the child of an object with variables IN the object instance name?

`location_1`, `location_2` are MCs containing `hidden_1`, `hidden_2` MCs etc.

And I'd ideally like to target the hidden objects with increasing integers inside a for loop. I've removed the for loop for ease of reading in the below:

```
var i = 0;
var cacheNum = 0;    

var locMc = this["location_"+(i+1)]; // This works
var hiddenMc = locMc.this["hidden_"+(cacheNum+1)]; // This doesn't work!
```

What I'd ideally like to be possible is:

```
var i = 1;
var cacheNum = 1;

var hiddenMc = location_i.hiddenMc_cacheNum;
```

Many thanks,
Nick

Comment: Take out `this`. But why do you want to do it this way when arrays are much easier to handle?

Comment: Does loc_mc["location_1"]["hidden_1"] exist?

Comment: `location_1` is a MC containing `hidden_1`, `hidden_2` etc. Please see refined question- should be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for object access by name is the same as array access by number:

```
object[value];
```

In the case of arrays, the value will be a number:

```
var myArray:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
myArray[0]; // "a"
```

In case of objects, the value will be a string:

```
var myObject:Object = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
myObject["a"] // 1
```

When accessing variables in the current object, you must use `this`, as in your example. But when using different objects, you just use the bracket notation directly:

```
var hiddenMc = locMc["hidden_"+(cacheNum+1)];
```

If the object is a [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) (like Sprite or MovieClip) and the value you are accessing is a child (as in your case), you can also use the [getChildByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29) method:

```
var hiddenMc = locMc.getChildByName("hidden_"+(cacheNum+1));
```

Like any expression, you can string accesses this way:

```
this["location_"+(i+1)]["hidden_"+(cacheNum+1)]
```

But as you can see, this is not readable and very error prone. The best way would be to store those hidden MC's in an array and access them from there. It simplifies the code because you don't need to append "hidden_" when accessing them, is usually faster and will never clash with other children with similar names.

Comment: Thanks! Understood: 
`var locMc = this["location_"+(i+1)];
trace(locMc["hidden_"+(cacheNum+1)]);`

Comment: Added an example similar to your request.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to bypass encapsulation by allowing code to manipulate the inner workings of an object. Do that at your own peril. Instead, provide some way for the outside object to have access on a limited basis or to be able to ask the object containing those values to perform work upon them on the caller's behalf:

```
public class Hidden()
{
    private var _hiddenValue:int = 5;
    public function get hiddenValue():int
    {
        return _hiddenValue;
    }
    public function screwWithTheHiddenValue():void
    {
        _hiddenValue += 25;
    }
}

public class Nosey()
{
    var hidden:Hidden = new Hidden();
    var result:int = hidden.hiddenValue;
    // result should be 5
    hidden.screwWithTheHiddenValue();
    result = hidden.hiddenValue;
    // result should now be 30;
}
```